# Adding a conditional in gsp file

Tags: grails, gsp

I have a situation where I get a value as a string and want to do a <= check on it inside my Grails GSP file.

For example.

```
<g:set var="dueAmount" value="${bean.dueAmount}"/> 
<span class="pay-onetime-btn-wrapper ${dueAmount <=0 ?'show':'hide'}" >bla bla </span>
```

I get the following error.

> java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Which makes sense as the `bean.dueAmount` is a string. How can I format it as a number or be able to a <= value comparison on it?

Thanks

Comment: Still throws the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your value is a double or floating value. So you can use `toDouble()` instead. Also, call `toString()` for the safe side before it.

```
<g:set var="dueAmount" value="${bean.dueAmount.toString().toDouble()}" />
<span class="pay-onetime-btn-wrapper ${dueAmount <=0 ? 'show' : 'hide'}">bla bla</span>
```

Comment: When I do a getClass() on it it returns "class java.lang.String"

Answer (score 0):

Grails has a `toInteger()` function

```
<g:set var="dueAmount" value="${bean.dueAmount.toInteger()}"/> 
<span class="pay-onetime-btn-wrapper ${dueAmount <=0 ?'show':'hide'}" >bla bla </span>
```

Comment: Do I need to import anything into my .gsp page. I get another error now. "Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0.00"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:458)"

Comment: if this is coming from xml, you might need to do `.text().toInteger()`. If you can create a repro case that would help the most.

Comment: No it's just coming from a controller as a string.

Comment: When I do a getClass() on it it returns "class java.lang.String"